# Image was not loaded sometimes properly from Assets folder in UWP?

Tags: c#, image, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have my OwnControl(userControl).In that control,I have an Image element(RangeSelectionIcon).
I had created 3 new object for this UserControl and added this control to my StackPanel in my Page.The image won't be loaded properly to all 3 userControls.Most of the times,the image loaded for only one control and the other two was not loaded.The image path was also given correctly. I don't know what the issue was ? My complete project [link(Source Code)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/100BxqLhxRb19XFWI31g7-7aRQ-_2DwzT?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Image was not loaded sometimes properly from Assets folder in UWP?

We can reproduce your problem, it looks `SvgImageSource` was not rendered correctly. for this scenario, we have a workaround that  `RasterizePixel` and re-rendered svg. during the testing, it could work well, please refer the following code.

```
<Style x:Key="RangeSelectionIconStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,5,6,0" />
    <Setter Property="Source">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SvgImageSource
                RasterizePixelHeight="20"
                RasterizePixelWidth="20"
                UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/SelectRange.svg" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Yeah its working. But what is RasterizationPixel ? If I set the RasterizationPixel Width and height as 20 . The Image appear doesn't looks like 20x20 ? If I increase the RasterizationPixel Width and Height, the image size decreases ? Can u explain it, How it Works ?

Comment: The size (in logical pixels) to use for SVG decoding operations, for more please this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource.rasterizepixelheight?view=winrt-22000)